# Set checkbox validation if checkbox unchecked

Tags: angular, validation, checkbox, angular6

In my Angular 6 application's register form, I have a checkbox which is already checked. I need to check whether the user has unchecked the checkbox and if it is so I want to display an error message.

This is my checkbox in .html file,

```
 <div class="form-group">
       <div class="round">
            <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="checkbox33"
                  formControlName="agree">
             <label for="checkbox33"></label>
        </div>
        <small class="text-muted">Agree to our <a href="#" class="link">Terms
                  Of Use</a> and <a href="#" class="link">Privacy Policy</a>.
                </small>
        <span *ngIf="!worldWideRegisterForm.get('agree').valid" class="text-danger">You should agree!</span>

  </div>
```

This is my ngOnInit() in .ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.worldWideRegisterForm = new FormGroup({
      'userName': new FormGroup({
        firstName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        lastName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
      }),
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      'phone': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'address': new FormGroup({
        line1: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        line2: new FormControl(null),
      }),
      'area': new FormGroup({
        'province': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'city': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'postalCode': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      }),
      'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
      'agree': new FormControl(true, Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

Comment: If the user can't uncheck the box, why don't you just disable it ?

Comment: Thank you @trichetriche, you are correct. But according to the requirement, I couldn't disable it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the angular validator `requiredTrue`

```
'agree': new FormControl(true, Validators.requiredTrue)
```

For error

```
<div *ngIf="myTrue.hasError('required')">
   Agree the T&C    
</div>
```

official link https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#requiredTrue

Comment: Thank you so much @Sheik, it seems there are lot of ways to solve my problem. And thank you for sharing the documentation reference as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `'agree': new FormControl(true, Validators.required)`
try it with `'agree': new FormControl(true, Validators.pattern('true'))`.

Comment: Thank you @riorudo, I could be able to do the exact same thing by writing custom validation for that. But this is much easier. I hope to add my answer also here. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by writing custom validation for checkbox and got the exact output as other answers. I like to share my answer as well.

This is my .html of checkbox,

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="round">
             <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="checkbox33"
                  formControlName="agree">
             <label for="checkbox33"></label>
         </div>
         <small class="text-muted">Agree to our <a href="#" class="link">Terms
                Of Use</a> and <a href="#" class="link">Privacy Policy</a>.
              </small>
         <span *ngIf="!worldWideRegisterForm.get('agree').valid" class="text-danger">
           <span *ngIf="worldWideRegisterForm.get('agree').errors['checkBoxIsForbidden']">Agree to our terms & conditions.</span>
              </span>
  </div>
```

This is what I added to my .ts file

```
'agree': new FormControl(true, [Validators.required, this.forbiddenCheckBox])

//fuction to check the checkbox
 forbiddenCheckBox(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    if (control.value === false) {
      return {'checkBoxIsForbidden': true};
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FromBuilder:

- *TS:*

```js
exampleForm: FormGroup; 
Constructor(private formBuilder:FromBuilder)
{
 this.exampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({  
  password:['',Validators.requiredTrue],  
  agree:['',Validators.requiredTrue] }) 
 }
```

- *HTML:*

```html
<section [formGroup]="exampleForm">
<p>
<mat-checkbox formControlName="password">
</mat-checkbox>
</p>  
<p><mat-checkbox formControlName="agree">
</mat-checkbox>
</p> 
</section>
<button [disabled]="validForm.invalid">Valid
</button>
```